# UWP ICommand parameter always null

Tags: c#, uwp, icommand

when trying to execute an ICommand, it always throws an exception due to the parameter being null.

When I manually print the variable being passed to ICommand with Debug.WriteLine, it works perfectly.

This is the command itself

```
    private CatalogBase<T> _catalogBase;

    public DeleteCommand()
    {
        _catalogBase = new CatalogBase<T>();
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _catalogBase.Delete((int)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

The button with the parameter and command bound:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding CustomerId}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
```

And this is *CustomerId* being referenced above:

```
    public int CustomerId
    {
        get { return _customer.CustomerId; }
    }
```

Again, manually printing *_customer.CustomerId* returns the correct one, and not null.

Anyone knows what could cause this? Thanks in advance.

Full xaml and viewmodel below:

```
<Page
x:Class="Hovmand.View.Domain.CustomersPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:page="using:Hovmand.ViewModel.Page"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <page:CustomerViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Create" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete" DataContext="" CommandParameter="{Binding CustomerDomainObject.CustomerId}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding CustomerDomainObject, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="0,12,0,12" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Padding="20,0,0,0" Text="Name"  Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Phone" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Mail" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Company" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Adress" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="48">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="1" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="5"/>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Viewmodel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Hovmand.Annotations;
using Hovmand.Model.Database;
using Hovmand.ViewModel.Base;
using Hovmand.ViewModel.Commands;

namespace Hovmand.ViewModel.Page
{
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ICommand _createCommand = new CreateCommand<Customer>();
        private ICommand _deleteCommand = new DeleteCommand<Customer>();
        private ICommand _updateCommand = new UpdateCommand<Customer>();
        private HovmanddbContext dbContext = HovmanddbContext.Instance;
        private Customer _customer = new Customer(); 

        public CustomerViewModel()
        {
        }

        public Customer CustomerDomainObject
        {
            get { return _customer; }
            set
            {
                _customer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Debug.WriteLine(_customer.CustomerId);
            }
        }

        public int CustomerId
        {
            get { return _customer.CustomerId; }
        }

        public int Cvr
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.Cvr; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.Cvr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string CompanyName
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.CompanyName; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.CompanyName = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.Address; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.Address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Phone
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.Phone; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.Phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Mail
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.Mail; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.Mail = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int FkContactId
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.FkContactId; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.FkContactId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int FkLocationId
        {
            get { return CustomerDomainObject.FkLocationId; }
            set
            {
                CustomerDomainObject.FkLocationId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public List<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return dbContext.Customers.ToList(); }
        }

        public ICommand CreateCommand
        {
            get { return _createCommand; }
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand
        {
            get { return _deleteCommand; }
        }

        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get { return _updateCommand; }
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of the XAML and/or your view model, but my guess is that the DataContext of your AppBarButton is not your customer, thus causing {Binding CustomerId} to fail and return null.

Comment: Sorry, I have now updated the OP with the full code of the xaml and viewmodel files.

Comment: Recreating this locally and hardcoding the Customer.CustomerId to a value, your original code seems to work (though in the XAML you posted, the button is setting the DataContext to null, so that won't work). I would suggest double-checking your ICommand implementation (I notice it takes a Customer type parameter in your ViewModel, but the implementation at the top of your post doesn't have that) and maybe consider using {x:Bind} instead of {Binding} so you get compile-time errors and Intellisense support.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry the datacontext in the button was from a previous attempt. The value was not there before.
Thank you, I will have a go at that.